# I need information on LEGO part #3001 in Milky White with Sparkles

Tags: colour

Have a 3001 part i have come across with a color i've never seen before. It seems to be a milky white but with glitter in it. New style logo with pip on short side.

Any ideas to where it came from?

Comment: If you have any additional information about where you came across this part, any pictures, etc. that you can include in your question (rather than in the comments to an answer), that might help others supply more information.

Answer (score 5):

According to a comment from Jan.k 1974 on [the source you mentioned](https://www.flickr.com/photos/maxx361/5494084763/) (in your comment to 62Bricks answer):

> The milky white brick dates to 2005 and has been been made exclusively for the Allianz Arena (Munich soccer stadium) model in Legoland Günzburg. I remember they sold spares of these in packs of 5 for 1.99 after the grand opening

This is confirmed by Maxx3001 in reply (emphasis added):

> […] that's the left brick *with slight sparkle* in it.

At the time of posting, [ND Toys was listing these at $2.39 on BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?itemID=264&colorID=60) under "Milky White" with the description:

> MILKY WHITE 2X4 BRICK WITH SPARKLES (from LL park spare parts)

The arena, and the milky white bricks can be seen in [this shot on the LEGOLAND website](http://www.legoland.de/en/Explore/Activities/Miniland/Allianz-Arena/):
[image: Allianz Arena]

Answer (score 2):

You may have what is commonly called a "test brick." Many of these were manufactured by the Bayer company in Germany. LEGO had Bayer test various designs and colors for their evaluation before deciding whether to put them into regular production.

One recognized authority on these bricks is the collector Maxx3001, who documents his extensive collection on Flickr. In his comment on [this trans-red glitter test brick](https://www.flickr.com/photos/maxx361/8549334712/), he makes reference to the existence of milky white glitter bricks. He may be able to give you more information on your brick.

Comment: Maxx is the user i got the part from. He has little info on the part. He has a pic of the part to the left here https://www.flickr.com/photos/maxx361/5494084763/

Comment: Bayer also stamps letters on the test bricks not the LEGO logo like i have mention above.

Comment: Some test bricks do have the LEGO logo on them.

Comment: It may or may not be a test brick is not an answer. I ask for some detailed info and you just gave speculation and a source that has already gave all the info he knows. From the source we have so far this is NOT a test brick. Im sorry to get kinda rude but i want to get to the facts, speculation has been done for a while now. I would like to hear from someone who knows about this part.

Comment: And asking for details on a piece for which you have not posted an image, and not indicating where you got it and what you already know about it is not a sincere question. Sorry to be rude, but if you are not going to provide complete information, you're going to get speculation.